# Phonegap - handleopenurl

Tags: cordova, url

There seems to be no conclusive answer for this one although I've seen it mentioned a few times.

Can anyone help me work out why my handleOpenURL handler isn't triggering on app launch?
Using PG – 4.2.0-0.24.1

I've a handleOpenURL which works fine when the app is running. Assuming therefore that my Info.plist URL scheme definition is fine.
I've read all sorts of articles about this suggesting that here is an ‘invokeString’ variable that contains the URL on launch but that isn't working and also I noted elsewhere that that is deprecated.
All the other documentation seems to suggest that I just need the one handler. a
Other note suggesting that the handler needs to be in HEAD section of index.html..
Anyway – the upshot is that I am stuck.
Anyone got any suggestions or an example project?

Thanks
dr

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
I had to go edit the native part of the app and added a couple of extra lines.
In the AppDelegate.m file of the core iOS App – I added the following code to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
if (launchOptions == nil) {
  NSLog(@“launchOptions nil”);
} else {
  // Get any SourceApplication data
  NSString urlPlus = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
  // Get the URL object
  NSURL urlData = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
  // Append //// seperator and then the URL string (absoluteString)
  urlPlus = [urlPlus stringByAppendingString:@“////”];
  urlPlus = [urlPlus stringByAppendingString: urlData.absoluteString];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlPlus];
  [self.viewController processOpenUrl:url];
}
```

Basically – it captures the url passed on app launch, grabs the data from the dictionary and then calls the standard processOpenUrl method..
I do slightly more than required here as I am also interested in finding out which app originated the URL call. For this I simply concatenate the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey value with the URL with a known separator (////)
Then in the app js – I use the built-in handleOpenURL handler with some extra code to check and split out the components.

```
function handleOpenURL(url) {
  var launchURL = "“;
  var launchSource = ”“;
  if (url.indexOf(”////“) > 0) {
    launchURL = url.split(”////“)[0];
    launchSource = url.split(”////“)[1];
    window.setTimeout(function () {
    alert('handleOpenURL: ‘ + ”launchURL: “ + launchSource + ”<br>“ + ”launchSource: “ + launchURL);
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    launchURL = url;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
    alert(’handleOpenURL: ‘ + ”launchURL: “ + launchURL);
    }, 1000);
  }
};
```

Note: by editing the core AppDelegate.m file you are going ever-so-slightly off reservation in that if you ever use ”phonegap platforms remove ios" and then add it back in then you’ll lose the code. Sure there is a way of working with that but I haven't looked into it..

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this 
[self.viewController processOpenUrl:url];
will cause your url to be shortened if it is quite long. This is because processOpenUrl directly converts an NSURL into a string, and thanks to Apple, this will cause an abbreviation of the URL using an ellipsis (...). I already filed a bug report for Cordova iOS and asked them to use url.absoluteString instead of just url to prevent this bug.